# Map gestures to mouse buttons

Tags: mac, mouse, multi-touch

I do like the mac mouse. touch sensitivity is nice. But the precision and number of buttons on my gaming mouse is much better. It seems to work on the mac just fine, but only left/right click and scroll works.

Is there a way to map swipe gestures to different buttons on the mouse? For exampe if have a main button on either side of the mouse, that when on my pc work as back/forward in a browser. I also have a button mapped to a script that brings up a code editor. Windows+Left/Right go to the previous/next workspace (I primarily use linux actually). So I would like to be able to do similar things on the mac, but a gogole search only brought up mapping gestures to keyboard commands, not the mouse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net) (free)

[image]

I don't have a multi-button mouse to test with, but it should support mapping gestures to arbitrary buttons.

Comment: The only 'gestures' I can map to mouse buttons are three finger swipe left/right/up/down, but it work. Theres a ton more options to. Still works like a charm. Marked as answer. Thanks.

Comment: There's actions for other gestures though. (Like *Mission Control*, *Lookup word under cursor*, *Smart Zoom*, and *Move Left a Space*.)

Comment: It's not free anymore! Is there any other option to do this without any software??